# How to join multiple messages into just one message in Node-Red?

Tags: node-red

Node 1:

```
{
  topic: "cur_freq",
  payload: 600000
}
```

Node 2:

```
{
  topic: "min_freq",
  payload: 600000
}
```

Node 3:

```
{
  topic: "max_freq",
  payload: 1200000
}
```

In Node-Red, how to **join these 3 messages** (from three different nodes) in just one message, based on topic?

```
{
  payload: {
    "cur_freq": 600000
    "min_freq": 600000
    "max_freq": 1200000
  }
}
```

I've tried the Join node with these settings, but debug shows nothing:

[image: Join node]
[image: Flow]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't given the join node any completion criteria.

You need to tell it to wait for 3 message parts.

Answer (score 1):

To clarify one way to define the completion criteria:

You need to inform the number of messages the system will join. In your case is 3:
[image]